# UML Activity Diagram: Create Link Object Action Example

Tags: uml, activity-diagram, model-driven-development

I am looking for a toy example of the usage of a "create link object action" with at least one other link action in a UML activity diagram.  I can find definitions of what this action does but no examples - so I only have a guess as to what it does.

For instance, "Executable UML: A Foundation for Model-Driven Architecture" suggests a "create link" action does the following "relate A to B across association."  I imagine this example creates a look up table?

Comment: What is this _create link object action_? Where from did you get that?

Comment: @qwerty_so What about "16.6.3.3 Create Link Action"  and its specialization "16.7.3.3 Create Link Object Actions" in the UML 2.5.1 specs?

Comment: @Christophe Probably :-) Honestly that part is one I never read...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *link* is the instance of an association, and a link object is the instance of an association class:

> **16.7.6**: Link object Actions operate on link objects, which are instances of AssociationClasses.

We are far from system design, where the organisation of activities is specified in broad terms and the details are implemented in a programming language.  Here we are in low-level actions that are meant for visual programming.

Looking at the definition of this action in the UML 2.5.1 specs:

> A CreateLinkObjectAction is a specialized CreateLinkAction for creating a link object (an instance of an AssocationClass). A CreateLinkObjectAction has the same semantics for link creation as a CreateLinkAction, except that its endData must be for an AssociationClass and the new link is a link object that is placed on the result OutputPin. If a link object matching the given endData already exists, and all the Association ends are unique, then this is placed on the result OutputPin, and no new link object is created.

So in your toy example, you'd need to refer to a class diagram with an association class, for example:

[image: A class Purchase Order associated with class product, the association class being line item]

In this case, your toy example would have a CreateLinkObjectAction called `add product to order` with two input pins: one for the `PurchaseOrder`, one for a selected `Product`, and an output pin for the newly created line. The output pin might feed another action such as `determine quantity`. As a source of inspiration, but to fine tune and complete, it could look like:

[image: Diagram corresponding to the description above]

Comment: Later on, could you query an array of LineItems for all of those containing a certain product?

Comment: @JordanMcBain that's the idea of the association in general and the association class in particular.  The navigability from Product to PurchaseOrder would guarantee efficient finding of linked instances at runtime.  I'm not too familiar with UML used as a visual programming tool, but as far as I understand, you'd do this either using a ReadLinkAction starting from a Product instance,  and getting the PurchaseOrders, which then let you find the LineItem.  Or you'd do this directly iterating through the link objects and checking with ReadLinkObjectEnd action that the product matches.

Comment: @JordanMcBain What seems missing in the UML specification, is the possibility to find the link objects directly from one end,  i.e. a kind of ReadLinkAction that would return both the related link object and the other end. The current wording does not seem to allow this in a single step, whereas this is how such a search would be implemented in reality.